# Usage of AlternativeLanguageCodes in Google Cloud Speech to Text API v1p1beta1 RPC

Tags: go, google-api, speech-recognition

I am working on Google Cloud Speech to Text API in RPC v1p1beta1 with its go client. The API works as expected but if alternativeLanguageCodes are set in the RecognitionConfig it does not answer.

```
GoogleRecognitionConfig: &speech.StreamingRecognitionConfig{
            SingleUtterance: c.SingleUtterance,
            InterimResults:  false,
            Config: &speech.RecognitionConfig{
                Encoding:        speech.RecognitionConfig_LINEAR16,
                SampleRateHertz: 8000,
                LanguageCode:    lang,
                // AlternativeLanguageCodes: []string("en-US"),
                SpeechContexts: []*speech.SpeechContext{
                    {Phrases: c.Phrases},
                },
            },
        },
```

I am aware it's in beta but I am wondering if anyone else is having issues as well or it's just a bug in my code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this today (c#, 1.0.0-beta02) but I never get alternative language codes results, only for primary language code.

```
ENGINE = SpeechClient.Create();
ENGINE_CONFIG = new StreamingRecognitionConfig()
{
    Config = new RecognitionConfig()
    {
        Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
        SampleRateHertz = settings.ArchiveSampleRate,
        LanguageCode = firstLanguageCode,
        ProfanityFilter = false,
        MaxAlternatives = Constants.MASTER_SETTINGS.SpeechRecognitionAlternatives,
        SpeechContexts = { new HintsManager(settings).GetHintsBasedOnContext(Contexts) }
    },
    InterimResults = Constants.MASTER_SETTINGS.RecognitionConfigSettings.InterimResultsReturned
};

// NOTE: 10062019 - ADD ALTERNATIVE LANGUAGE CODES HERE
// NOTE: 10062019 - ADD ALTERNATIVE LANGUAGE CODES HERE
// NOTE: 10062019 - ADD ALTERNATIVE LANGUAGE CODES HERE
foreach (var alternativeCode in otherAlternativeLanguageCodes)
{
    ENGINE_CONFIG.Config.AlternativeLanguageCodes.Add(alternativeCode);
}
```

EDIT: After upgrading yesterday to new Beta, Nuget:

```
Install-Package Google.Cloud.Speech.V1P1Beta1 -Version 1.0.0-beta03
```

Everything seems to be working ok. The only thing I noticed was that interim results are never returned?

Comment: I guess this may indicate that it's a defect on the server side of things. I hope someone @ Google can give us a hint.